# TFS 2018 - Save a close button

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I'm working with TFS 2018 and I want to prevent my users from clicking on the "Save and close" button in the form of a work item. Is it possible to remove the button?

![image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on why you want to do that? There's no way to remove the save and close button, but there may be a different way of achieving the same objective.

Comment: I think Daniel is alluding to the fact that you can use Area Path permissions to remove Edit permissions. Or that you can use workflow rules to prevent people from changing certain fields in certain states.

Comment: I commented, perform an extension where I hear the events performed on a work item (as shown in the link that I will leave at the end of the answer).
In this extension I use the "onSaved" event which is called whenever I save the changes in my work item.
There is my problem, if the user presses on the "Save" button my action runs without problems, now, if my user presses the "Save and close" button the changes in the fields that I do within the method do not apply " onSaved. "


https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/work-item-form/workItemPage.html